# Find the maximum elements that the set can contain.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $S$ be a subset of $ \{1,2,3 . . . 9\} $ such that the sums formed by adding each unorrdered pair of distinct numbers from $ S $ are all different. What is the maximum number of elements that $S$ can contain.

One such set can be $\{1,2,3,5\}$. While $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ can not be such a set as 1 and 4 have the same sum as 2 and 3.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the largest subset that you can find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in the work yourself:

Naively, how many distinct sums could there be?

Hence, conclude that there are at most 6 elements.

If we had sums of 17 and 3, then we must have the elements $\{ 1, 2, 8, 9 \}$.

Hence, conclude that there are at most 5 elements.

Find a subset of 5 elements that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: There can be 15 different sums i.e. 3 to 15. But how can I conclude that there can be at most 6 elements?

Comment: If we have 7 elements, how many pairwise sums are there? (Note: We can have a pairwise sum of $9+8=17$.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get how you concluded that there are 5 at most elements.

Comment: If there are 6 elements, we must have pairwise sums of 17 and 3 right? Can that be allowed?