# How many integers do we need to select from a set from 1 to 20 to guarantee there will be two of the same pairwise sum?

Tags: combinatorics, integers, pigeonhole-principle

What is the intuition for this? I currently know that there are 38 possible sums, and I'm stuck after that. Any intuition would help, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean two pairs that have the same sum?

Comment: so from 1-20, (2,5) have the same sum as (1,6)

Comment: So yes, that is what I meant. Sorry for the confusing phrasing.

Comment: Here's a similar problem for the set from 1 to 9 - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622065/find-the-maximum-elements-that-the-set-can-contain/3622091#3622091

Answer (score 0):

If we have 2 choosen numbers we have one pair, with 3 - 3 different- so two different sums. and so on. With n numbers we can create possibly $ \frac{n*(n-1)}{2} $ different pairs. We have to find such n, that this amount would be grater than 38. Then we can make use from Pigeonhole principle we can say that there would exist at least two same pairwise sum.

$ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}>38 \\ 
n^2-n>76 \\
n^2-n-76>0 $

after making some maths i find that n has to be at least 10

Comment: You've established that 10 is sufficient. Conversely, is there a set of 9 elements that have pairwise distinct sum?

Comment: Isn't it sufficient that from 9 numbers i can make 36 pairs and put each pair to each pigeonhole?

Comment: I believe that's not possible. Can you state such a set? As an example, if you have the sums of 3 and 39, then you must have the numbers $1, 2, 19, 20$, which give $1+20 = 2+19$.

Comment: indeed, my mistake then